# Extended class function must implement interface

Tags: php, symfony

I have class `Article` which extends bundle class `Article`

`class Article extends BaseArticle`

The `BaseArticle` has method `getImages`

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getImages(): Collection
{
    return $this->images;
}
```

The problem is when this method is called I get this error:

`Return value of Odiseo\BlogBundle\Model\Article::getImages() must implement interface Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection, null returned`

Im not really sure how I can get `null`, because this only happens in admin panel and it works good in public articles page. Can it be problem with extending entities ?

Comment: What is "admin panel"?

Answer (score 0):

somewhere, the line

```
$this->images = new ArrayCollection();
```

is missing or prevented (note, you need a use clause for this: `use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;`).

There are two possible causes I see here:

1. The `BaseArticle` (so, the `Article` from the bundle) does NOT have in its `__construct()` the before mentioned line.
2. The `BaseArticle` has that line, but your `Article`'s constructor overrides (doesn't call parent constructor) and thus prevents it, and should either call the parent constructor OR have that line itself.

Both those causes lead to the method returning `null`, since the property is not initialized properly (proper initialization would be the line at the top), which is obviously not implementing the `Collection` interface, hence the error message.

Alternatively, something is setting the `images` property to `null`